# Why does Gateway with void return is making async flow but it does sync when it return value? Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, gateway

I am new with Spring Integration. I was making some tests I realized the behavior of my app changes when the `Gateway` return `void` or return `String`. I'm trying to process the flow in the background (async) meanwhile I return a http message. So I did a async pipeline

```
@Bean
MessageChannel asyncChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel(1);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel asyncChannel2() {
    return new QueueChannel(1);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel asyncChannel3() {
    return new QueueChannel(1);
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
PollerMetadata customPoller() {

    PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger = new PeriodicTrigger(2000, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
    periodicTrigger.setFixedRate(true);
    periodicTrigger.setInitialDelay(1000);
    
    PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
    poller.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(500);
    poller.setTrigger(periodicTrigger);
    return poller;
}
```

3 Activators

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "asyncChannel", outputChannel = "asyncChannel2")
public String async(String message) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        log.info("Activator 1 " + message);
        return message;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("I don't want to sleep now");
    }
    
    return "";
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "asyncChannel2", outputChannel = "asyncChannel3")
public String async(String message){
    log.info("Activator 2 "+ message);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return message;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("I don't want to sleep");
    }
    
    return "";
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "asyncChannel3")
public String result(String message) throws InterruptedException {
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    log.info("Activator 3 " + message);
    
    return message;
    
}
```

I receive a message from Controller class

```
private final ReturningGateway returningGateway;

@PostMapping("/example")
public ResponseEntity post() {
    
   returningGateway.processWhileResponse("Message example");
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of("Message","Http Done. Check the logs"));
    
}
```

The `gateway`

```
@Gateway(requestChannel = "asyncChannel")
public void processWhileResponse(String message_example);
```

The curious thing is when the `gateway` returns a `void` it making the process async so I can see the http message `"Http Done. Check the logs"` first, then I go to the logs and I see the async execution. but when the `gateway` returns a `String` I see the logs first and then the http message.

So I need the `gateway` returns a value but it keep the async way so I can get a http message

could you give a hand?

Sorry if I'm not using the right term. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I need the gateway returns a value but it keep the async way so I can get a http message.

As long as you return some non-async type, it is going to block your code on the gateway call and wait for that return value to come back. Even if your flow behind that gateway is async, it still waits for a reply on the `CountDownLatch` barrier for `replyChannel`. In case of `void` return type there is no reply expectations and gateway exists immediately after sending a request message.

You may consider to have a `Future` as return type, but it still not clear when you would like to get the value: before returning from your controller method, or it is OK already after.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#async-gateway